# Flutter row layouting by percentage with divider

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to split my box in two parts seperated by a divider line I tried something like this:

```
Card(
    child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        children: [
            Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                width: 25.w-8-4,
                child: const Text("box1")),
            const VerticalDivider(
                color: Colors.red,
                width: 16,
                thickness: 2,
            ),
            Container(
                color: Colors.indigo,
                width: 75.w-8-4,
                child: const Text("box2"),
            )
        ],
    )
)
```

using the [sizer](https://pub.dev/packages/sizer) package. Subtracting -4 each because of margin of the `card` and -8 because of the verticalDivider. This results in this view:

[image]

But unfortunately I can't seem to see the vertical divider (space is just white?). And also it would be great to have a way to say, "please consume about 25% and 75% of the space" to the left and right container, of what is left after the divider line is drawn. Is there a way to put it like this? This would make it easier to use padding/margin at the containers too. Without having to subtract stuff from width of the containers respectively.

Thanks a lot

Comment: you want to above design?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you considered using `Expanded` ?

```
return Row(
 children:[
  Expanded(
    flex:25,
    child: Container(
       color: Colors.green,
       child: Text('box1'),
        ),
      ),
  Expanded(
    flex:75,
    child: Container(
       color: Colors.blue,
       child: Text('box2'),
        ),
      ),
   ],
);
```

Add the margin/padding accordingly.

Comment: how to make sure, that  the divider is visible?

Comment: Add a ```divider``` between two ```Expanded``` and provide a thickness or color of your choice.

Comment: Isnt easier to read flex: 1 and flex: 3?

Comment: Yes, it is. I wrote it as 25 and 75 so that everyone can get the logic.